# Added myself to /etc/sudoers but sudo still asks for password

Tags: sudo

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file edited with visudo, but I'm still asked to enter my password when doing sudo.

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
petruza  ALL=(ALL) ALL
petruza  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I had this running in previous OS installs but now it doesn't work.

My main need for this is to automatically execute `xampp` at startup and not having it asking me for the password.

Comment: That's not a good idea to do as it opens a big security hole! Consider just allowing the individual app (smaller hole). What Mac OS version and how did you edit `/etc/sudoers`, with `visudo`?

Comment: The permissions given in your sudoers file are complete overkill! Which xampp are you talking of? Automated start-up usually that can be done with a LaunchAgent without loosening any restrictions in sudoers!

Comment: @klanomath Ok! please tell me how!

Comment: @user3439894 How do I allow xampp individually? yes I edited it with visudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your modifications of the sudoers file is needed if you start xampp with a launch daemon:

1. Create a file *org.xampp.startup.plist*  in /Library/LaunchDaemons with `sudo touch/nano ...` and the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
           <key>Label</key>
           <string>org.xampp.startup</string>
           <key>ProgramArguments</key>
           <array>
                   <string>/bin/bash</string>
                   <string>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp</string>
                   <string>start</string>
           </array>
           <key>RunAtLoad</key>
           <true/>
           <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
           <string>/tmp/org.xampp.startup.stderr</string>
           <key>StandardOutPath</key>
           <string>/tmp/org.xampp.startup.stdout</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   If you installed XAMPP somewhere else please modify `<string>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp</string>` accordingly.
2. chown/chmod the file:

   ```
   sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.xampp.startup.plist
   sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.xampp.startup.plist
   ```
3. Load the daemon with:

   ```
   sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.xampp.startup.plist
   ```
4. If everything runs well, you may remove the following part of the plist:

   ```
           <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
           <string>/tmp/org.xampp.startup.stderr</string>
           <key>StandardOutPath</key>
           <string>/tmp/org.xampp.startup.stdout</string>
   ```
5. Restore the default sudoers file with visudo:

   ```
   ...
   root ALL=(ALL) ALL
   %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

   ## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
   #%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

   ## Same thing without a password
   #%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but only starts apache. MySQL won't.
I added another Launch Daemon with `xampp startmysql` but won't work either. And stdout and stderr files have no hint about this.